# Can I add a function in engine.js?

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc, dwr, reverse-ajax

Our web application is using reverse ajax. It checks user's session every 30sec and produces console logs(see logs below). Is it possible to add a function after/before the log is printed? and how?

**Logs**:

```
POST localhost:8080/dwr/call/plainpoll/ReverseAjax.dwr
200 OK    30s    
engine.js (line 1542)
///////////////
POST localhost:8080/dwr/call/plainpoll/ReverseAjax.dwr
200 OK    30s    
engine.js (line 1542)
///////////////
POST localhost:8080/dwr/call/plainpoll/ReverseAjax.dwr
200 OK    30s    
engine.js (line 1542)
```

Comment: how is the code you shared related to java and spring-mvc?

Comment: @prash: it is a java based web application that uses spring dependencies...